# Is there a way to listen globally for newly opened windows in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Similar to how I could listen to key presses globally using `KeyboardFocusManager` is there a way to listen globally for any opened (`setVisible` call) `JFrame` or `Window` in Swing?

I could poll `Window.getWindows()` to do this, but I was wondering if I could do this in an event-driven way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }
}, AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
```